# Find an equation for the plane parallel to the x-axis and passing through two given points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I need to find an equation for the plane parallel to the x-axis and passing through two given points.

One vector is parallel to the $x$-axis : $\langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle$

The other is found by using the two points $A (2, 1, -1)$ and $B (3, 2, 1)$. This gives the vector $\overrightarrow{AB} = \langle 1, 1, 2 \rangle$

I calculated the vector product between $\langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 1, 1, 2 \rangle$ and obtained $\langle 0, -2, 1 \rangle$

My answer is $-2y + z = -3$ but the book gives $2y -z =3$.

**My question is : can you divide the equation for a plane by $\bf{-1}$ on both sides? Or is there a mistake in my calculations?**

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the book? Obviously you can divide or multiply for $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what a planar equation means. If

$$-2y+z=-3$$

then can we show that

$$2y-z=3$$

(and vice versa) to show that they're equivalent?